# Android App Compact theme Error

Tags: android, android-intent

Hello I' making this project in Android when i start the dialog Activity from Main Activity.

These are the related files:
Main Activity:http://pastebin.com/xyDbBSj4
Dialogs Activity:http://pastebin.com/f6jGC1CH

I have this error on logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.android4dev.navigationview, PID: 30736
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android4dev.navigationview/com.android4dev.navigationview.ui.activities.DialogsActivity}:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:122)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
at com.android4dev.navigationview.ui.activities.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:36)
at com.android4dev.navigationview.ui.activities.DialogsActivity.onCreate(DialogsActivity.java:43)
```

Comment: what is the BaseActivity ?

Comment: I mean it is extends what ?

Comment: change:  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"> with : android:theme="@style/Base.AppTheme" >

Comment: @BhavdipPathar First of all, thanks for your quick answer, this is the Base Activity:http://pastebin.com/H74v6ibt

Answer (score 0):

1- You should declare that your application will be stylized using Theme.AppCompat in your Android Manifest.
Something like this:

```
<activity
      android:name=".my.packageactivity.MyOwnActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"/>
```

2- Or maybe declare that the whole application will be stylized using AppCompat.

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
```

3- If you want to set your own style later, you'll have to create a style.xml.

3.1- Using the whole application:

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyOwnStyle">
```

3.2- Using the activity>

```
<activity
          android:name=".my.packageactivity.MyOwnActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:theme="@style/MyOwnStyle"/>
```

And then set the parent to Theme.AppCompat inside your new style.xml file:

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyOwnStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
       [...]
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Hi@filipe.costa01, thanks for your time, but the solution doesn't fix my problem

Comment: Can you post your android manifest and style.xml, please? Maybe you forgot to declare something there and I can help you identify it

Comment: These are the files:
Android Manifest:http://pastebin.com/LA8mLJtB
style:http://pastebin.com/h0cun0dz

Comment: Did you try change this <activity
           android:name=".ui.activities.DialogsActivity"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"> to <activity
           android:name=".ui.activities.DialogsActivity"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"> ?